Customer Community Plus Portal User can't edit own contact record
As the title suggests, our Customer Community Plus Users can't edit their own Contact record on Experience Cloud.
As an example, one of the fields we have visible on the Contact page in Experience Cloud is "LinkedIn profile" - we want our users to be able to edit that for themselves.
In terms of security:

Organizational Wide Default Sharing Settings for the Contact object is:
a. Default Internal Access -- Public Read / Write
b. Default External Access -- Private

There is one Sharing Rule for the Contact object, that only gives Read Only access to Contact objects with a specific application status. 

Under Digital Experience > Settings, we added a Sharing Set (based on other StackExchange questions) that allows Contacts to edit their own contact information. While debugging, we enabled this for all users. 


However, when a user goes to Experience Cloud, they're still unable to edit their Contact's LinkedIn profile field.
And, when I look at the Sharing Hierarchy for that Contact, it looks like the "Self" relationship is still Read Only (as opposed to Read/Write)
Is there a permission I'm missing to allow users to edit their own contact?

what is the CRUD on Contact for the profile used by the Experience user?

@cropredy It is Read only! I had checked the Edit box as well, but I was running into an issue where Experience users were able to edit all Contact records Linkedin Profiles (whereas, I want them to only be able to edit their own).

If helpful, the behavior I want is that:

Users can view (read only) all Contact Records
For their own Contact record, they're able to edit specific attributes


You want users to Read all Contacts across the Account they belong to but only edit their own contact?

Correct! If you look at the screenshot in #2, this was the Sharing Rule I thought would work so that all portal users could read all the contacts (minus certain ones that shouldn't be visible); screenshot in #3 was what I thought was needed to allow write access to their own contact.

I wasn't aware you can mix sharing sets and sharing rules

Based on brief googling, I thought it was possible! Is there a way to do this with just sharing rules?

Answering this in case it's helpful for other folks

I needed to ensure that the CRUD permission for the Contact object included the Edit permission (it did not)

When I had initially done this, I had reverted the change because the pencil edit icon was showing up in Experience Cloud for all profiles (not just a user's own profile). That is apparently the expected behavior - there's an idea posted that asks that the pencil / edit icon be removed if a user doesn't actually have edit permissions.


