FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception: ContactAccessLevel
Context
I'm trying to give a Customer Community Plus Portal Users edit access to their own Contact Record, by using a flow. To note is that they don't own their contact record (all contact records are owned by the system administrator)
In the flow, I fetch

The Portal User's associated Contact
Create a share record between the Contact Id, Portal User Id, and give ContactAccessLevel = Edit

However, when I was debugging the flow, I received the following error:
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: field integrity exception: ContactAccessLevel 
(trivial share level Edit, for organization with default level Edit

But, when I look at the OWD for the Contact, it has

Default External Access = Private


What is the default level referring to here?

The error is caused by having the Default Internal Access set to Public Read/Write (API name is "Edit"). This might just be a glitch in sharing. One way you can work around this would be to set the Default Internal Access to Public Read Only, then create a Sharing Rule to share from All Internal Users to All Internal Users with the Edit permission, and then you should also be able to make the manual shares for edit permission for individual contact records.

Thank you, @sfdcfox! One question - my understanding of the Internal vs External Access, was that External Access was the setting for folks accessing Salesforce via Experience Cloud, vs Internal Access was for folks accessing data via the Lightning Experience (or Salesforce Classic). Is that not accurate?

@NiharikaRay You are correct. Internal Access is for LEX and Classic users, External Access is for everyone else, which I think includes Communities, Digital Experiences, and Site.com users.

Got it! In that case, since I'm debugging the permissions for the Digital Experiences users, would changing the Internal Access to Public Read Only help?

@NiharikaRay That was my suggestion. It should allow you to create the share records you need, and you can use a sharing rule to restore full read/write access for all internal users.

Got it! I accepted the answer - while it didn't solve my use case, it may solve others!

My issue ended up being something more silly - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/423312/customer-community-plus-portal-user-cant-edit-own-contact-record?noredirect=1#comment605537_423312
